# How can i deploy react app to global network?

Tags: reactjs, networking

I run my react app and have:

```
- Local:            http://localhost:5000      │
- On Your Network:  http://192.168.*.*:5000
```

This link run in my local network is ok

But in other network is not found

How can my website public to global network. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The two IP addresses you are listing are both local IP addresses and can only be accessed in the local network. See for example https://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip.
In order to make your React app accessible to the whole world, there are two steps needed:

1. Build your app
2. Deploy your app to a hoster

**Build App**

You run `npm run build` in order to create HTML, CSS and JavaScript files from your React source files. Those are the files that the browser can read. The script saves the files in your project in a folder called `build/static`.

**Deploy App**

A static file hoster will take those files and make them accessible to the whole world. One of the easiest solutions is Netlify Drop, see https://app.netlify.com/drop. You can just drag and drop the `static` folder onto the Netlify website and your page is live.

Comment: thank you so much, so it impossible to make my computer is a sever without a third party like  Netlify Drop?

Comment: There are ways to do this, but I strongly suggest NOT to do that. There are a lot of internet users which try to hack servers. Making your computer accessible to the internet is therefore not a good idea, except you know how exactly how to make it in a secure way. Except from that, when you turn off your computer, the website is not accessible anymore. The servers from hosters are available 24/7. Then, Netlify provides you a domain name for your website, so it's easy for other people to find your website. And there are probably many more reasons.

Comment: And by the way, Netlify is free to use for personal projects.

Comment: Thanks for warning me but i still want to make my computer like server for testing and know about action of server. Please show me how to do this.